# Items in Minecraft available in all Worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created a book in Minecraft with about 20+ pages. It's a manual to brewing for the others playing on my server. My Server runs totally without mods. Now my question:

Is it possible to keep this Book permanently available in Minecraft, even if I change world?

I am talking about things like extracting the Book, to add it manually or give it a permanent ID in Minecraft itself. I don't want to write it again and again :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a book generator to generate the book so you have the instant command on hand.  This way all you would have to do is copy and paste the command in chat or a command block and activate it and, voila you have the book you need whenever you need it.  (Make sure to save the command somewhere like your sticky notes.)

Comment: Also what version of Minecraft do you run?

Comment: book generator? It is a Mod/Plugin, isnt't it? 1.9

Comment: No just search book generator in google and you will find a site that allows you to get a written book with a command.  This is the generator I've used:     http://minecraft.tools/en/book.php

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a book generator to generate the book so you have the instant command on hand. This way all you would have to do is copy and paste the command in chat or a command block and activate it and, voila you have the book you need whenever you need it. (Make sure to save the command somewhere like your sticky notes.)

This is the generator I've used: http://minecraft.tools/en/book.php

A command looks something like this: `/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["{\"text\":\"Hello World!!!\"}"],title:"Create a book",author:Jason_,display:{Lore:["A book to use in all my worlds"]}}`

Small commands can be copied and pasted in chat by pressing `T` for talk.

Chat can only hold certain amount of letters so you would have to give yourself a command block by typing this command in chat:  `/give (Your name) minecraft:command_block`

Paste your command you generated in the command block.  (Command blocks don't have a limit in the amount of lettering space.)  Then activate the command block with a button, pressure plate, redstone block, ect.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be possible in Vanilla Minecraft without mods. Unless you do what @Jason_ did, the only way would be to download some sort of mod that would let you transfer items between worlds.